# Installing tmux but getting "dyld: Library not loaded Referenced from: /usr/"

Tags: install, homebrew, tmux, dynamic-library

I try to do

```
brew install tmux
```

it installs, but, probably due to previous failed and not fully removed non-brew attempts to install both it and libevent, when try to use tmux I get

```
$ tmux
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libevent-2.0.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/tmux
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I tried to install libevent but I got:

```
$ brew install libevent
Warning: libevent-2.0.21 already installed, it's just not linked
```

so I tried

```
$ brew link libevent
```

but I got

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.21... 
Warning: Could not link libevent. Unlinking...
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.21/include/event2/util.h
Target /usr/local/include/event2/util.h already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name
To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

so I tried

```
$ brew link --overwrite libevent
```

but I got

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.21... 
Warning: Could not link libevent. Unlinking...
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/include/event2/util.h
```

so I tried

```
$ sudo brew link --overwrite libevent
```

Password:

but I got

```
Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew link`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.
```

I'm stuck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mine had the same problem.

```
$ tmux
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libevent-2.0.5.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/tmux/1.9a/bin/tmux
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Tried to install `libevent` but it was already there, not linked yet:

```
$ brew install libevent
Warning: libevent-2.0.21 already installed
$ brew link libevent
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.21
To relink: brew unlink libevent && brew link libevent
```

I solved it by doing exactly what was suggested above:

```
$ brew unlink libevent && brew link libevent
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.21... 4 links removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libevent/2.0.21... 25 symlinks created
$ tmux -V
tmux 1.9a
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I had to uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 70):

```
brew uninstall --force tmux
brew install tmux
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: This worked for me, but without the need of `--force`.

Comment: Accepted answer didn't work in my case, but this did. Thanks

Comment: This worked for me as well (the accepted answer didn't work)..

Comment: only this worked!

Comment: No need for --force

Comment: had to uninstall and reinstall

Comment: Thank you, in my case, it was for tmate (which is a fork of tmux) and this worked great. I'm on Catalina 10.15.5.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue with tmuxinator, And get that error in my case I upgraded tmux with:

```
brew upgrade tmux
```

Answer (score 3):

My tmux also started shooting this error recently.
In my case simply calling `brew upgrade tmux` helped.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was

```
 brew install pkg-config
 rm configure
 sh autogen.sh 
 ./configure 
 make
 make install
```

Also see
http://whiletruecode.com/post/installing-iterm2-and-tmux-osx
but do the above instead of the broken link at the last step.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above steps but those did not work for me though.
In my case I just did not have the missing version of libevent. I double, triple checked it but it seems that version isn't served by brew or someway.

What I did have is libevent-2.1.6.dylib. I made a symlink from libevent-2.0.5.dylib to the aforementioned file and tmux seems to work again. Perhaps tmux should be updated?

Comment: I understand that it seems i'm not answering the question. I had the exact same error message and symptoms. My problem, however, wasn't the badly linked libevent but just the a whole different version.

My addition could help other people having the same issue i had.

Comment: @Tetsujin actually, the OP didn't really ask a question, if we're going to split hairs. This answer solved it for me without losing my tmux session. Thanks Kozie for posting.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after updating macOS. To resolve

- if you installed `tmux` from source code, than reinstall again, it will link the new libevent.
- if used Homebrew run `brew uninstall --force tmux; brew install tmux`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue and tried the above-mentioned solutions but it did not work. What I found out was that there was a weird dependency with openssl and since I installed openssl via `pip` it was not linked properly to /usr/local/opt and linking via brew was also not working. A simple solution was to uninstall both openssl and libevent via brew and reinstalling them via brew.